# Name collisions between method names and variables for selenium page elements

Tags: ruby, rspec, yaml, capybara

The problem I am facing is that capybara methods such as **fill_in** are calling methods that share the same name as variables for selectors.

I have a yaml file that contains the variable names and the selectors they represent.

selectors.yml --

```
general_information:
  first_name: 'first-name'
  last_name: 'last-name'
```

My spec opens the yaml file and creates variables using the yaml hierarchy by using resursive-open-struct.

```
describe 'this is my spec'
  p = RecursiveOpenStruct.new(YAML.load(File.read('spec/support/selectors.yml')))

  describe "Enter Info Page" do
    it "checks for first name field", :smoke do
      goto_page_info p.urls.enter_info
      expect(find p.general_information.first_name).to be
    end
  end
```

The problem that I am facing is that several of my tests have selectors that share a name with methods in other files. Capybara will call the methods instead of trying to find the element.

Example error:

fill_in p.general_information.first_name will give an error that states "wrong number of arguments (given 0 expected 1). This is because it is trying to call a method in another file that is named "first_name".

How do I avoid this naming collision problem?

Comment: Is using `p['general_information']['first_name']` a possibility?

Comment: Can you provide an example of these collisions because `p` is the receiver here which means this is a method that is transmitted to the object `p` I am unsure how this would cause a collision. Without an explicit receiver I could understand ambiguous determination but in this case I cannot.

Comment: None of the methods shown in your code are Capybara methods other than `find`.  If you have included a `find` method into your test class that collides then call `page.find` or `Capybara.current_session.find`  instead - otherwise, as @engineersmnky has stated, your example isn't really showing where your issue is.

Comment: Also, you might want to rename `p`, which is already defined in Ruby.

Comment: The find method isn't the conflict in this example. One conflict that occurs is one where p.application.user_name tries to call a method named "user_name" that is located in a separate file.

Comment: @CaptainKidd The only way methods in other files would get called is if you're including them into the scope of the object methods are being called on in some way.  You're not including stuff into the global scope are you?

Comment: @ThomasWalpole In the specs themselves I am not including anything that would cause a conflict. Would spec_helper.rb cause the conflicts since spec_helper is loaded before each test?

Comment: @CaptainKidd You have to be including something otherwise a conflict is impossible. `spec_helper.rb` itself wouldn't cause the issue, but any includes you've added in there could, especially if you're including anything into the global scope.

Comment: @CaptainKidd Specifically in this case it would be how/where the module that includes the `first_name` method is included